# Bisecting the area and perimeter

Tags: geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$, $AB=16$, $AC=15$, and $BC=13$. Point $D$ is on $AB$, and point $E$ is on $AC$ so that $DE$ bisects both the area and perimeter of triangle $ABC$. (In other words, both $DA+AE$ and $DB+BC+CE$ are equal to half the perimeter.) Find $DE^2$.

Comment: It's generally preferred that you give us some idea of where you came across this problem, what you know about it, how far you got in solving it, where you got stuck, whether you understand the definitions of the terms used in it, anything to make it easier for people to write an answer you'll find useful.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you want. There is a family of traversals cutting both $AB$ and $AC$, each of which halves the area of $ABC$. There is a family of traversals cutting both $AB$ and $AC$, each of which halves the perimeter of $ABC$. You seek one that is a member of both families, right?

Comment: Yep, that is correct.

Comment: @mathgeek \\ That was an intriguing problem. I do hope that you will show a proper appreciation to the person who expended so much effort on the answer by ACCEPTING his answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $d:=AD$ and $e:=AE$. Then the perimeter bisection becomes

$$d+e=(16+15+13)/2=22 \\ e=22-d$$

Using Heron's formula, the area of $\triangle ABC$ is

$$\frac14\sqrt{(16+15+13)(-16+15+13)(16-15+13)(16+15-13)}=6\sqrt{231}$$

so you want $\triangle DAE$ to have an area of $3\sqrt{231}=\sqrt{2079}$. But in order to compute that area using Heron again, you need the distance $f:=DE$. Let's for the moment assume we had that distance given.

\begin{align*}
\frac14\sqrt{(d+e+f)(-d+e+f)(d-e+f)(d+e-f)}&=\sqrt{2079}\\
(22+f)(22-2d+f)(2d-22+f)(22-f)&=4^2\cdot2079\\
\bigl(f^2-22^2\bigr)\bigl(f^2-(22-2d)^2\bigr)&=-33264\\
4d^2f^2 - f^4 - 88df^2 - 1936d^2 + 968f^2 + 42592d - 267520 &= 0 \tag1
\end{align*}

You can use the law of cosines to describe $f$, or rather $f^2$:

\begin{align*}
\cos A = \frac{d^2+e^2-f^2}{2de} &= \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}
= \frac{15^2+16^2-13^2}{2\cdot15\cdot16}=\frac{13}{20} \\
20(d^2+(22-d)^2-f^2)&=13(2d(22-d)) \\
66d^2 - 20f^2 - 1452d + 9680 &= 0 \\
f^2 &= (66d^2 - 1452d + 9680)/20 \tag2
\end{align*}

Now if you plug $(2)$ into $(1)$ you get

\begin{align*}
\frac{231}{100}d^4 - \frac{2541}{25}d^3 + \frac{27951}{25}d^2 - 33264 &= 0 \\
d^4 - 44d^3 + 484d^2 - 14400 &= 0 \tag3 \\
\{11-\sqrt{241}\approx-4.5,10,12,11+\sqrt{241}\approx26.5\} &\ni d
\end{align*}

The first solution is negative. The last one is greater than $22$ and would therefore lead to negative $e$. So you have two possible choices for $d$ and therefore two possible choices for $D$ and $E$. These two choices are symmetric with respect to the angle bisector at $A$, so the quantity $f^2$ you are asked for remains the same. Plugging either of these solutions into $(2)$ will give you that $f^2$.

Of course, solving the quartic equation $(3)$ is a bit uncomfortable (unless you let a computer do it for you), so you might want to simplify that step. You could have thought about the symmetry before seeing the solutions: since $\triangle DAE$ is determined by its perimeter, its area and the angle at $A$, this description is fully symmetric. So you could use that symmetry in your equation as well. Write $d$ as $d=11+x$ so that whenever $x$ is a solution, $-x$ is a solution as well. Then $(3)$ becomes

$$x^4 - 242x^2 + 241 = 0\tag4$$

which is simply a quadratic equation in $x^2$.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote it, but awesome solution.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$EK$ is parallel to $CD$ , $K$ on $AB$

$CKD$ and $CED$ have a common base and equal height so they have the same area.
It follows that area $CKB$ is half the area of $ABC$. 
Therefore $K$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

$\frac{\text{AK}}{\text{AD}}=\frac{\text{AE}}{\text{AC}}$

$\frac{8}{AD}=\frac{AE}{15}$

$\text{AD}*\text{AE}=\text{AK}*\text{AC}=120$

$AD+AE=22$ (see the previous solution by MvG)

This gives the two solutions 
${AD,AE}={10,12}$ or ${AD,AE}={12,10}$

From here use the Law of Cosines to get $\cos A = 13/20$

and

$\text{ED}^2=10^2+12^2-2*10*12 *\frac{13}{20}=88$

Comment: OK, my question (from the comment I deleted by now) was stupid, somehow I had a wrong image in my mind. Got that right (thanks to your comment) and also created it outside of my mind so it can be shared. Hope you don't mind me editing your post. This is indeed a nice shortcut to that $\{10,12\}$ result.